# Why can I use memcpy to copy one object variable to another

Tags: c++

I have this class

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    int* tab;
};

int main()
{
    TestClass a;
    a.tab[0]=8;
    a.tab[1]=5;
    TestClass b;
    memcpy(b.tab,a.tab,sizeof(int)*2);
    cout << b.tab[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and I want to copy **tab** from **a** to **b tab**. But this code doesn't work. 
I tried to copy **tab** to dynamic array and it worked.

```
TestClass a;
a.tab[0]=8;
a.tab[1]=5;
int* b=new int[2];
memcpy(b,a.tab,sizeof(int)*2);
cout << b[0] << endl;
```

Can someone explain why first code doesn't work but second works?

Comment: Everything you're doing is undefined behavior. `a` contains an uninitialized pointer, and you try to put stuff at the location pointed to by the uninitialized `a.tab`. Pointers need to be initialized just like other fundamental types. You can't just declare a pointer and expect it to point to a valid memory address which can store an object.

Comment: You should really use copy constructors instead. `memcpy` can be a nasty function.

Comment: There's no explanation, both programs are wrong. Sometimes wrong programs work.

Comment: You haven't stored a pointer in tab, All undefined behaviour, and would crash if you were more lucky.

Comment: As a general advice bump your warnings to the maximum possible level and treat all warnings as errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're causing undefined behavior by trying to use the subscript operator with an uninitialized pointer. Instead of doing any of these, use `std::vector` or `std::array`, depending on what you are trying to achieve:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TestClass
{
public:
    std::vector<int> tab;
};

int main()
{
    TestClass a{ { 8, 5 } };
    TestClass b{ a };
    std::cout << b.tab[0] << '\n';
}
```

This keeps it simple and maintainable. STL containers have more friendly value semantics and they are in general easier to use, harder to abuse.